# .d.ts file can be imported using "import XXX" but default export does not exist

Tags: typescript

First, creates .d.ts file like the following, not using default exports.

```
// foo.css.d.ts
export const a: string;
export const b: string;
```

Then, other TypeScript file imports it.

```
// bar.ts
import * as foo1 from "./foo.css";
import foo2 from "./foo.css";
```

As far as I remember, TypeScript conforms ES module specification and cannot import using `import XXX` from not including default export module. Why I can import it? Some options exist to enable the importing way in TypeScript?

( `allowSyntheticDefaultImports: false` and `esModuleInterop: false` in `tsconfig.json`)

Comment: Could you rewrite your second to last paragraph to be a bit more clear about what you're asking? Are you saying it is working and you're not expecting it to? Or is there some error you're getting that you haven't listed above? For whatever it's worth, on TypeScript 3.1.1 with those flags set to false, I get TS1192: Module '"foo.css"' has no default export, which makes sense to me.

Comment: @TylerChurch I just create sample code (https://codesandbox.io/s/yp8xymmoqx). `index.ts` does not occur any errors and I expect to get errors using `import XXX from "./xxx";` not using default exports.

Comment: it's not clear to me what tsconfig.json options that codesandbox is using. If you try this here: https://repl.it/repls/EvenInfiniteOpensoundsystem the error occurs (you may need to hit Run to see it)